# std::swap error assignment of read-only reference

Tags: c++, stl

```
void sort_this(std::map<BITMAP*,MAPS>::iterator  start,std::map<BITMAP*,MAPS>::iterator endd)
{
    for(auto itt=start;itt!=endd;itt++)
    {               
        for(auto it=start;it!=endd;it++)
        {        
            if(itt->second.type > it->second.type)
            {                                
                std::swap(*it,*itt);
            }                
        }        
    }       
}
```

i need to swap `*it` and `*itt` ,it gives this error.

```
files\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.7.1\include\c++\bits\move.h|177|
error: assignment of read-only reference '__a'|
c:\program files\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.7.1\include\c++\bits\move.h|178|
error: assignment of read-only reference '__b'|
```

edit: purpose of this function is to arrange elements of a map. according to second.type

Comment: You can't swap a pair with another one belonging to another map, you might want to swap the maps elements

Answer (score 7):

`std::map` iterators are **always** constant with regard to the keys (think about it, if you change the key value the underlying tree risks being destroyed!), you can swap the values however:

```
std::swap(it->second, itt->second);
```

Disclaimer: this may or may not be what you are looking for, as I have no idea what the purpose of the swap is.